# windows 10 pyautogui multiple desktops

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I made an automation with pyautogui. Windows 10 has multiple desktops feature.

Can I run my automation in a desktop and use some other desktop at the same time?

Comment: I just tried. Didn't work, it actually got carried forward to the new desktop. Hope that helps

Comment: I also tried. As I remember it didn't work. Thanks